# How can I override touch event in two different ViewController in in Xamarin or xcode objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, touch

I have two view controller that doing different stuff with the touch event. they are connected with a simple segue. I override touch methods like that (Xamarin):

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
    UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
    //my code
}

public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
    UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
    //my code
}

public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    //my code
}
```

but if I touch the screen in first ViewController it gets fired in both ViewControllers. How can I prevent that?
Here is my VC classes:

```
partial class PSViewController : UIViewController
{
    public PSViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
}
partial class PCViewController : UIViewController
{
    public PCViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
}
```

also in addition to touch events I have ViewDidAppear on both VCs:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

-B

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specifc and show us your ViewControllers and how they are arranged?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe thanks for reply. I have two ViewController class (.cs) file and there is a segue from one to another. after the segue is performed, the touch event gets fired on both ViewControllers code behind. It causes few bugs and instability in our app and I want to prevent that. It should be easy to fix, but I couldn't find anything specific about that. is that a normal thing to happen?

Comment: Can you show the code of these two viewcontrollers (maybe reduced to the main parts)?

Comment: In addition to what Sven suggested, also share the UI hierarchy (only a description)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I added few lines of my code hoope it helps

Comment: @MohibSheth They are connected with a segue. Please et me know if you need more info

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help, because we can't see any hierarchy or connection. something like `class ViewControllerA : UIViewController { /*constructor and overloads*/ }` would help (for both viewcontrollers)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe  thanks for your prompt reply. I have added whatever you asked,Hope  that helps? :)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe any help? :)

Comment: If you can upload an example, I could have a look. From this code, I can't say anything. Sorry